# Why a transaction couldn't be found with bitcoin-cli after 11 confirmations?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I made a new address with `bitcoin-cli getnewaddress`:

```
39WqU8NJJasFjmaS2J4424UGVJn8Tqvh82
```

Then I initiated a transfer from some online service.
The transaction is displayed with 11 confirmations:
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/cc09117205515389ed618acd31b6e691e363446c5ce5cce94b24cc74701fbd74

Now, I am trying to verify this with bitcoin-cli:

```
$ bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 0 true true 39WqU8NJJasFjmaS2J4424UGVJn8Tqvh82
[
  {
    "address": "39WqU8NJJasFjmaS2J4424UGVJn8Tqvh82",
    "amount": 0.00000000,
    "confirmations": 0,
    "label": "",
    "txids": [
    ]
  }
]

$ bitcoin-cli gettransaction cc09117205515389ed618acd31b6e691e363446c5ce5cce94b24cc74701fbd74
error code: -5
error message:
Invalid or non-wallet transaction id

$ bitcoin-cli -getinfo
{
  "version": 190100,
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "blocks": 481192,
  "timeoffset": -1,
  "connections": 10,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 923233068448.9053,
  "chain": "main",
  "walletversion": 169900,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "keypoololdest": 1584106964,
  "keypoolsize": 997,
  "unlocked_until": 0,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "warnings": ""
}
```

What should I do in order to verify locally success of the transaction?

Why balance didn't increase?

The node is configured with `prune=4096`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node is not fully synced, when you posted this it was only synced up to block 481192 (look at `blocks` under `getinfo`).

Once the node catches up to the chain tip the tx should display properly.

Comment: Actually, I was expecting that it would sync much faster because this is a dedicated server and also that bitcoin would output indication of progress or something like that.. Now it's clear, thanks!

Comment: If you check the debug.log it will output the sync progress as it goes.

Comment: cool! I found it, that's useful. Btw it synced and I see my positive balance. Thanks!